# tcpip.sys - Windows 8 crashes (bluescreen)

Tags: networking, windows-8, bsod

Whenever I start my [Plex Media Server](http://www.plexapp.com/) on Windows 8 (64-bit), my computer crashes after some minutes, displaying something others called a bluescreen ...

On that screen, Windows 8 tells me that "an error occurred", and that a file named `tcpip.sys` is the problem.

Google tells me now that `tcpip.sys` is a driver and that somehow, the driver and my hardware or whatever have a problem (so it's not Plex that's guilty).

But what exactly is now the problem? Do I need a new driver? If yes, which one is the one I need?

Comment: We need you to post more information from the BSOD. There are programs that exist that will let you copy and paste this information. I would also post this question on the community website for `Plex` so perhaps you can get more localized help through their community.  Based on my research on `tcpip.sys` there is likely an application on your system which while trying to connect to the internet is crashing hence the `tcpip.sys` I suggest you remove `Plex Media Server` to verify if your system still crashes.

Comment: If you want any chance of us helping be sure the log being generated is the full crash dump per these instructions: http://forums.plexapp.com/index.php/topic/23320-enabling-automatic-crash-dumps-on-windows/

Comment: And, Plex being a server would use tcpip.sys at some level... Maybe not directly and maybe directly so ruling that out 100% is not a definite...

Answer (score 1):

`tcpip.sys` is the Windows TCP/IP stack.  It's pretty much a basic component of Windows.  As it is central to network communication most of the time, there's a number of other drivers interacting with this that could be a cause of the problem.

Issues from this driver directly are really very rare.  My first suspicion is that malware has modified this file.  You should boot from a WinPE disk and restore from a known good version if possible.

Something off the top of my head for a moment though: Did you try to apply a well-known utility that modifies `tcpip.sys` to allow more than 10 half-open TCP connections in order to improve Bittorrent performance?  It's likely not compatible with Windows 8 and you should roll it back if you did this.

Another thing to check: If you look under Device Manager, you may notice, under "Network adapters", the presence of one or more "miniport" drivers.  These drivers filter stuff going in and out of a real network adapter.  Security software (such as an antivirus suite) and VPN software might install these, and these may be causing an issue or conflict.  I imagine a problem with one of these might cause `tcpip.sys` to panic.  I've not heard of a "media server" type program installing a miniport driver but it could be possible.  You also may have an issue with McAfee firewall miniport drivers or similar.  Looking here could point to the culprit.

You also might try updating or reinstalling your Wifi drivers and supporting software.

Try updating your BIOS.  It could be a weird ACPI issue which having the latest BIOS could help resolve.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Start screen
- Type `Command Prompt`
- When Command Prompt comes up on the list, right click it and click Run as Administrator
- Type `sfc /scannow` into the Command Prompt

This command will scan system files, and if there is a corrupt file, it will try to fix it.
If this doesn't help, you could try running system restore. I am not totally sure how to run System Restore on Windows 8, but I think it would work to...

- Go to Start screen
- Type in `System Restore`
- And start it up

It will probably tell you what you need to do next to restore your system. When system restore is running, you will need to select a restore point that was created *before* you noticed the problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It would help to look at the systems `minidump` logs that are located in `C:\Windows\Minidump` files from the crashes with a debugger. You can either zip them and upload them all at once or you can upload then one at a time. As long as you provide a link to when the files can be obtained.

In the meantime, if you're running any malware applications (Kaspersky / Symantec / Avast / McAfee) then remove these and replace them with [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/). Running *multiple* malware applications will usually cause a conflict and result in a `Blue Screen`. Kaspersky has been known cause the same issues even when used alone. If you're using some other malware detection application then I'd suggest you remove it since the only application that you can be *sure* will run without bothering anything is the one provided by Microsoft.

- If you are using Kaspersky, use the following link to completely remove it. -
  [kaspersky.zip](http://support.kaspersky.com/downloads/utils/kavremover10.zip)
- If you are using Symantec, use the following link to completely remove it. - [Symantec removal tool](http://us.norton.com/support/kb/web_view.jsp?wv_type=public_web&docurl=20080710133834EN)

Comment: There are other great AV, and MSE is not perfect either: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=windows+security+essentials+bsod&oq=windows+security+essentials+bsod&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l4.1183468.1190803.1.1191012.18.17.1.0.0.0.260.2052.8j8j1.17.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.S50w7vUQuuE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aWM&fp=dcf3fdf2c24c0e41&biw=1280&bih=804

Comment: No one said it was perfect. But it is best suited since Microsoft built it for _their_ operating system. I'm sure that their are plenty of tools that do just as good / better jobs than MSE.